# Method for Back button not working when Time.TimeScale=0

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have written below code for Back button event.

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape))
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("PreviousLevel");
    }  
}
```

In almost all cases this is fine. But I have found a small issue. When the user pauses the game, this doesn't work. When the user pauses the game, I do Time.timeScale=0. Initially, I gave a thought of modifying pause method and instead of doing Time.timeScale=0, use a bool variable and modify other pause logic accordingly. But then I also realized that I have over 14 co-routines whose logic is heavily dependent on Time.timeScale and modifying those will take a lot of time.  They are heavily dependent on time.timeScale.

I wanted to know, is there any other method where I can write back button logic and which is not dependent on Time.timeScale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work, input polling in Unity is not dependent on the time scale.

Try by inserting a `Debug.Log` inside the condition, and you should see it in the console.

Watch out if you put the if inside `FixedUpdate` and not `Update`: in that case it won't work since `FixedUpdate` is completely skipped when time scale is 0.

However, if you want a "dirty" trick, you can slow the timescale to a very low number, without using 0, i.e.: 10e-8. But use it with a lot of care, since it can lead to unwanted behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Input is dependent on time scale: `GetButton()` works normally but `GetAxis()` works inconsistently, for example getting mouse movement with `GetAxis()` works as expected, but getting Horizontal and Vertical returns 0 when timeScale is 0. You can get around this by using `Input.GetAxisRaw()`.

It should also be noted that any axis also counts as a button, so you can also use `GetButton()` on those but the return value will be bool instead of float.